# Do While in php for two different dates

Tags: php, loops, datetime, while-loop, do-while

Want to alert Effective Date, till it meets the condition.

Code:-

```
$effective_date = '2020/09/03';
$last_date = '2020/12/03';

$last_date = new DateTime($last_date);
$effective_date = new DateTime($effective_date);
do{
    $edate = $effective_date->format('Y/m/d');
    echo "<script>alert('".$edate."');</script>";
    $nxtdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($edate)));
    $effective_date = new DateTime($nxtdate);
} while($effective_date > $last_date);
```

It alerts only one time, but my expectation is it should be alerted 3 times

Comment: `$effective_date > $last_date` is false from the start, therefore no iterations. Probably `while($effective_date < $last_date)` is what you want. It's "while" not "until".

Comment: Also, theres is no need for strtotime() and date(). You can manipulate your DateTime object directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It alerts only one time because your `while` condition is not correct.

Notice that the `do { ... } while (condition)` loop will run at least once and continue as long as the `condition` is `true`, not until it becomes `true`.

Change `while($effective_date > $last_date)` to `while($effective_date < $last_date)`:

```php
$effective_date = '2020/09/03';
$last_date = '2020/12/03';

$last_date = new DateTime($last_date);
$effective_date = new DateTime($effective_date);
do{
    $edate = $effective_date->format('Y/m/d');
    echo "<script>alert('".$edate."');</script>";
    $nxtdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($edate)));
    $effective_date = new DateTime($nxtdate);
} while($effective_date < $last_date);
```

Ouput:

```
<script>alert('2020/09/03');</script><script>alert('2020/10/03');</script><script>alert('2020/11/03');</script>
```

#### Update

If you want the `condition` to be checked before the statements inside the loop are executed, use the `while` loop instead:

```php
while ($effective_date < $last_date) {
    $edate = $effective_date->format('Y/m/d');
    echo "<script>alert('".$edate."');</script>";
    $nxtdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($edate)));
    $effective_date = new DateTime($nxtdate);
}
```

Comment: [Why this gets alerted?](https://3v4l.org/vf49Y) I don't want to execute if the effective date is greater

Comment: so you should use `while (condition) {...}`, because as I say before, `do {...} while (condition)` always run at least once (before the `condition` is checked)